# Plotly-Dash download DataFrame to CSV no longer works with send_data_frame

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

The following Python code snipped has been working for me up until very recently, and I cannot find documentation of any changes. I am attempting to write a Pandas DataFrame to disk as a CSV file with the `send_data_frame` function in Plotly's `dash_core_components` module.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash_extensions import Download
from dash_extensions.snippets import send_data_frame

layout = html.Div([
  ...
  ... # Trying to be as complete, but as brief as possible with my snippet.
  ...
  ... # The main gist is that there are 2 buttons on the page, one that
  ... # triggers a callback to download stock data (OHLC prices), and another
  ... # that saves the data to disk after it has been gathered.
])

# MAIN APP CALLBACK -- This downloads the OHLC data from Yahoo Finance.
@app.callback(
    Output('ohlcData', 'children'),
  [
    Input('button', 'n_clicks')
  ],[
    State('ticker', 'value')
  ], prevent_initial_call=True)
def get_ohlc_data(n_clicks, ticker):
  ohlc = getOHLC(ticker) # This works, but the method is not shown here
  df = ohlc.df

  # Write the OHLC DataFrame to a hidden DataFrame
  hiddenDF = df.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')

  return hiddenDF

# DOWNLOAD CSV CALLBACK -- This secondary callback finds the hiddenDiv and attempts to write it to disk as a CSV file.
@app.callback(
    Output('dataFrame', 'data'),
  [
    Input('button2', 'n_clicks')
  ],[
    State('ohlcData', 'children')
  ], prevent_initial_call=True)
def writeCSV(n_clicks, hiddenDiv):
  dfOHLC = pd.read_json(hiddenDiv, orient='split')
  dfOHLC.index.name = 'Date'
  return send_data_frame(dfOHLC.to_csv, 'OHLC.csv')
```

Last week when I ran this code I would get a popup window when I attempted to "download" or save the CSV file to disk. Now I do not even get that far, but instead get a warning (had to set `debug=True`) that states:

```
Failed component prop type: Invalid component prop `data` key `mime_type` supplied to Download.
Bad object: {
  "content": 
"[A really long string of characters]",
  "filename": "OHLC.csv",
  "mime_type": null,
  "base64": true
}
Valid keys: [
  "filename",
  "content",
  "base64",
  "type"
]
```

Please help!

Given the error message, I am guessing that the Output option `data` in `Output('dataFrame', 'data')` is suddenly an invalid parameter.

Comment: Interestingly, this code works when run in a Docker container but will not create the pop-up window to allow the download when run outside of Docker. Any ideas how to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `Download` component was migrated from `dash-extensions` to `dash-core-components`, the `mime_type` property was renamed to `type`. Your error suggests that you are creating a `Download` component using `dash-core-components`, but sending data using `send_data_frame` from `dash-extensions`.

If you use one or the other consistently, it should work. However, the `dash-core-components` component is the one that will be supported going forward, so I would suggest to use that one.